# How to specify eager loading globally for a resource in ActiveAdmin 0.5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have a page registered to a model in my ActiveAdmin application as follows:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do
  menu parent: 'Administration', priority: 2

  scope ...
  scope ...

  filter ...
  filter ...

end
```

The "Report" model/resource has a number of associations with other models. What is the best way to specify eager loading for some of the associations which also be applied to result of all scopes and filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override scoped_collection like

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do
  menu parent: 'Administration', priority: 2

  controller do
     def scoped_collection 
       Report.includes(:users, ....)  
     end
  end
end
```

UPD, Completely agree with  @TimoSchilling comment.

if you want to override `scoped_collection` use `super` and then append methods, in this way InheritedResource's `end_of_association_chain` will not be ignored.

So final code is

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do
      menu parent: 'Administration', priority: 2

      controller do
         def scoped_collection 
           super.includes(:users, ....)  
           # or 
           super.eager_load(:users, ....)  
         end
      end
    end
```

However in most all cases https://stackoverflow.com/a/29038410/246544#29038410 this answer will work great.

Comment: That way works but you should use `super` instead of `Report `, other wise you will lose things like auth or filtering.

Comment: @TimoSchilling, only inherited resource features will be loosen,  AA feature appending in ```find_collection```, which happening after ```scoped_collection```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is using built-in feature :)

```
ActiveAdmin.register Report do
  includes :users, :apples, :rhinos

  ...
end
```

YOu can read more about resource customization at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md

Comment: When using `includes` , I get a NoMethodError exception which says `undefined method includes for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0x000000062b60f0>`

Comment: Which version of activeadmin you are using?

Comment: Oh, it is really old - it was released about 2 years ago. The last version is 1.0.0 pre. Sorry, I can't help you with your version. Suggest you to update your question and write your version of activeadmin there.